# Total Unique Addresses Count of EOS

Tags: eosio.token, address

I need to find an API giving the total number of unique addresses used on the EOS blockchain.

For example, [this](https://etherscan.io/chart/address) page provides it for Ethereum.

You can also see a methodology for the cryptocurrencies that are on BigQuery Public Datasets [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/79303/23669) but unfortunately, EOS is not included in this dataset yet.

Is there a similar API or methodology for EOS?